# Can I create Stripe subscriptions manually in a React Native app using Firebase extension or do i need a webapp?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

Stripe React Native Subscriptions are web only?

Hi,

I have a react native app that allows users to set manage their stripe susbcriptions using the Firebase GetPortalLink. (Using the Firebase extension) However, the subscriptions have to be created for the first time in the Stripe website. This documentation saying web only makes it seem like i can't create stripe subscriptions manually?

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-payments/POSTINSTALL.md#subscription-payments-web-only

I have tried many implementations to add subscriptions but this makes it seem like I need a seperate web application to do it?  Could I make a corresponding React webapp that hits the same backend as the mobile app, to make them integrate seamlessly like Spotify? (Is this why Spotify subscriptions are not available in the app?)

Comment: I was able to manually create a subscription link but it wasn't tied to the firebase user, it makes a new customer in stripe that doesn't use the Firebase extensions which are needed for auth/differentiating premium subscribed users